# Find all real functions that satisfy: $f(x+y) = (f(x))^2 + (f(y))^2$, $x$, $y$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, real-numbers, functional-equations

I am trying to find all real functions that satisfy the property: $f(x+y) = (f(x))^2 + (f(y))^2$, $x$, $y$ real numbers. I tried to substitute $x$ and $y$ with $0$ but end up with nothing, then I tried substituting $y$ with $x$ and I get $f(2x) = 2(f(x))^2$, then I tried to prove that $f(0) = 0$ and I think I am missing an important step.

How can I proceed from here? If it isn't the wrong already.

Comment: Imagine you know $f(1)$. At how many other points can you get the value of $f$ knowing *just* $f(1)$? Use the given recurrence wisely. For example, you will know $f(2)$. Then using $y=1,x=2$, you'll know $f(3)$. SImilarly, you'll know $f(1/2), f(1/4)$ etc. Find the exact set of values at which $f$ becomes determined. Then, we can try to think about what happens "outside" that set.

Comment: How can I determine the exact set? Is it the set of positive rational numbers?

Comment: If $f(0) = 0$ then: $$0 = f(0) = f(x + (-x)) = f(x)^2 + f(-x)^2$$ but since each term is positive that gives $f(x)^2 = f(-x)^2 = 0$, and therefore: $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) = 0$. In general, if there's any $z$ for which $f(z) = 0$, then you can show that $f$ is the zero function by doing the same thing with $z = x + (z - x)$. Thus you may require the function to be strictly positive.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but this may be feasible with [operator calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_calculus), which is always an interesting avenue. Since $f(x+1)=f(x)^2+f(1)^2$, noting $f(x+1)=e^D f(x)$ where $e^D=e^\frac{d}{dx}$ is the [shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator), letting $y=f(x)$ and $c=f(1)$, then we have a differential equation of the form $e^Dy-y^2-c=0$. In other words, $y$ should obey $y+y'+\frac{y''}{2}+\cdots=y^2+c$.

Comment: Hint: first take $x=y=0$, and then take $y=0$ and $x$ general; that will give you very strong information about the possible values of $f$. Must $f$ be continuous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting $x=y=0$ tells us that $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=\frac 1 2$.

Now, $y=0$ gives us $$f(x)=f(x)^2+f(0)^2\tag1$$

Write $z=f(x)$. This presents us with $z^2-z+f(0)^2=0$. Therefore, the image of $x$ under $f$ is always a root of this equation. Can you take it from here, case by case?

Comment: So that would mean that $f(x) = 1$ or $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: And since $f(x) = 1$ can't possibly a solution because it doesn't satisfy the relation, the only real functions are: $f(x) = 0$, $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I misread your comment. My bad.  Yes, $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=1/2$ are the only solutions.

Answer (score 3):

$x = y = 0$ gives $f(0) = (f(0))^2 + (f(0))^2$, and since $f(x)$, which has the solutions $f(0) = 0, f(0) = \frac{1}{2}$. Case $1$ ($f(0) = 0$) gives that, if $y = -x$: $f(x + -x) = (f(x))^2 + (f(y))^2 \iff 0 = (f(x))^2 + (f(y))^2$, but since $f$ is a real valued function, both terms in the $RHS$ of the equation have to equal $0$, and since we made no assumptions about $x$, this means that $f(x) = 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbf{R}$. Case $2$ ($f(0) = \frac{1}{2}$) gives that, if $y = 0$, $f(x) = (f(x))^2 + \frac{1}{2}$, which has the only solution $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$. This means that the valid solutions are $f(x) = 0, f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$.